# How to fix TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'xy', 'width', and 'height' from a matplotlib.patches ellipse

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently doing a school project where I'm making a basic stick figure animation with Bézier Curves on Python. I just started on programming and I am in need of help.

I've successfully created a basic animation of a bunch of segments linked together forming a stick figure and I'm now trying to replace the sticks into ellipses that would move and rotate through time, following a set of Bézier Curves that I put into my code, just like my lines used to.

Since I cannot post images, I'll say that my stick figure moves from left to right in a humanoid walking motion. Each body part follows a specified path traced by the different Bézier curves.

With matplotlib.patches, I want to bring multiple Ellipses with the arguments Ellipse(xy, height, width, angle) so they can all replace my lines. I've made numpy arrays of all my different body part dots (I had 5 key frames, so I have 5 dots for each body part)

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

#This is to make the background of my plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-3, 50), ylim=(0, 25))
ax.set_title('Bézier Animation')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
cercte = plt.Circle((0.5, 21), 2, color='black', fill=False)




def init():

    cercte.center = (0.5, 21)
    ax.add_patch(cercte)
    return cercte

ellipses = []

links = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [1, 6], [6, 7], 
[6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12]])

for ii in range(len(links[:, 0])):

    ellipses[ii] = Ellipse()

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dsquared = dx**2 + dy**2
    result = dsquared**0.5
    return result

def ellipse(A, B):

    xy = (A + B) / 2
    width = 1
    height = distance(A[0], A[1], B[0], B[1])
    angle = np.arctan((B[1] - A[1]) / (B[0] - A[0]))

    return xy, width, height, angle

#These are all my arrays containing the coordinates of each dot needed
mte = np.array([[mte1[0], mte2[0], mte3[0], mte4[0], mte5[0]], [mte1[1], 
      mte2[1], mte3[1], mte4[1], mte5[1]]])

c = np.array([[c1[0], c2[0], c3[0], c4[0], c5[0]], [c1[1], c2[1], c3[1], 
    c4[1], c5[1]]])

e = np.array([[e1[0], e2[0], e3[0], e4[0], e5[0]], [e1[1], e2[1],  e3[1], 
    e4[1], e5[1]]])

cg = np.array([[cg1[0], cg2[0], cg3[0], cg4[0], cg5[0]], [cg1[1], cg2[1], 
     cg3[1], cg4[1], cg5[1]]])
cd = np.array([[cd1[0], cd2[0], cd3[0], cd4[0], cd5[0]], [cd1[1], cd2[1], 
     cd3[1], cd4[1], cd5[1]]])

mg = np.array([[mg1[0], mg2[0], mg3[0], mg4[0], mg5[0]], [mg1[1], mg2[1], 
     mg3[1], mg4[1], mg5[1]]])
md = np.array([[md1[0], md2[0], md3[0], md4[0], md5[0]], [md1[1], md2[1], 
     md3[1], md4[1], md5[1]]])

bs = np.array([[bs1[0], bs2[0], bs3[0], bs4[0], bs5[0]], [bs1[1], bs2[1], 
     bs3[1], bs4[1], bs5[1]]])

gg = np.array([[gg1[0], gg2[0], gg3[0], gg4[0], gg5[0]], [gg1[1], gg2[1], 
     gg3[1], gg4[1], gg5[1]]])
gd = np.array([[gd1[0], gd2[0], gd3[0], gd4[0], gd5[0]], [gd1[1], gd2[1], 
     gd3[1], gd4[1], gd5[1]]])

tg = np.array([[tg1[0], tg2[0], tg3[0], tg4[0], tg5[0]], [tg1[1], tg2[1], 
     tg3[1], tg4[1], tg5[1]]])
td = np.array([[td1[0], td2[0], td3[0], td4[0], td5[0]], [td1[1], td2[1], 
     td3[1], td4[1], td5[1]]])

og = np.array([[og1[0], og2[0], og3[0], og4[0], og5[0]], [og1[1], og2[1], 
     og3[1], og4[1], og5[1]]])
od = np.array([[od1[0], od2[0], od3[0], od4[0], od5[0]], [od1[1], od2[1], 
     od3[1], od4[1], od5[1]]])

#My bézier function
def bezier(A,t):
    return A[:, 0]*[(1 - t)**4] + 4*A[:, 1]*[(1 - t)**3]*t + 6*A[:, 2]*   
    [(1 - t)**2]*(t**2) + 4*A[:, 3]*(1 - t)*(t**3) + A[:, 4]*(t**4)

dots = []

dots.append(c)
dots.append(e)
dots.append(cg)
dots.append(cd)
dots.append(mg)
dots.append(md)
dots.append(bs)
dots.append(gg)
dots.append(gd)
dots.append(tg)
dots.append(td)
dots.append(og)
dots.append(od)

def animate(i):
    t = 1 / 200

    mtem = bezier(mte, t)

    bez = []

    for ii in range(len(dots)):

        bez.append(bezier(dots[ii], t))

    for ii in range(len(links[0, :])):

        xy, width, height, angle = ellipse(bez[links[ii][0]], bez[liens[ii][1]])
        #I'm not quite sure for this part right here
        ellipses[ii].xy = xy
        ellipses[ii].width = width     
        ellipses[ii].height = height
        ellipses[ii].angle = angle

    xc, yc = cercte.center
    xc = (mtem[0])
    yc = (mtem[1])
    cercte.center = (xc, yc)

    return cercte, ellipses,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(Fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=5, blit=True)
```

the rest of my code simply is inside an animate function that updates the values of the arguments in each of my ellipses and of my circle. I expect seeing an animation of my stick figure moving but with ellipses as body parts instead of sticks. However, nothing shows up since I got that type error. Is the solution related that I have to specify the initial position and angle of each ellipse in the init function? If that's the case, it's gonna take a while to do.

Comment: What are `A` and `B` supposed to be? `(A + B) / 2` implies that they're numbers, but then you use `A[0]` and `B[0]`, which means they're arrays. You never call `ellipse()` anywhere.

Comment: A and B represent arrays, each containing 5 coordinates into them. I want xy to find the middle between the coordinate A[n] and B[n], where n goes from 0 to the last argument in my array. I have a list of 12 arrays that replaces A and B depending on the situation. Also, I didnt want to put too much code in my question but I do use ellipse() later in my file. Should I add the rest that has ellipses into them?

Comment: The basic problem is (mostly) clear from the error message.  As the documentation shows, creating an `Ellipse` *requires* three arguments.  You supplied none of those.  The docs and tutorials include usage examples.

Comment: When you call `Ellipse`, you have to pass it `xy`, `width`, `height`, and optionally `angle`. These come from calling `ellipse()`. But I don't see where the arguments to `ellipse()` come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `ellipse` function, and pass the returned values to the `Ellipse()` function from `matplotlib`

```
for ii in range(len(links[:, 0])):
    xy, width, height, angle = ellipse(a, b)
    ellipses.append(Ellipse(xy, width, height, angle))
```

I don't see where `a` and `b` come from in your code, though. You'll need to add that code.

Comment: it tells me list object is not callable. Also, do you refer *ellipse as *ellipses or *Ellipse ?

Comment: I fixed it by splitting it into two statements. Now I think you can see what was intended better.

Comment: There, I added the rest. Again, I'm new to this, so sorry for the spam.

Comment: I still don't understand. You're setting all those coordinates *after* you do the loop that fills in `ellipses`.

Comment: Also, you can't assign to `ellipses[ii]` to create new list elements, it can only be used to replace existing elements. You have to use `ellipses.append()`.